# data structure for co-ordinate x,y which allows O(log n) searching on both x and y

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The data structure is used to store co-ordinates (x,y) and the query would be get max(x) where y>=k or get max(y) where x>=k. What kind of a data structure allows O(log n) searching on both x and y. If I have a binary tree, then it would only allow searching over either x or y.

Comment: You can have two separate binary trees, one for searching over x and other one for searching over y.

Comment: that won't be efficient. It will store each point twice. I want to avoid that!

Comment: So write it in the question. You only stated, that you want O(log n) searching, two trees meet that requirement.

Comment: in any case, it would be *two* data structure(trees). My question is about *one* data structure.

Comment: @usamec No. Two trees wouldn't work, as you would need one tree for every greater than condition. For example, for the criteria max(x) where y>6, you would use the y tree to search for tuples with y>6, but then the x tree would be useless as it contains all the data unfiltered and would only allow you to find max x on all the set of tuples...

Comment: You can use one balanced binary tree for answering question: What is max(x) when y > 6. You just need to add one piece of information for maximum x in given subtree of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use an R-tree for this. I'm not really familiar with it myself, but I think it is a common data structure for multidimensional data.

Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree